# Split Text String in R

Tags: r, string, split, text-mining

I have large list in `R` with more than 5000 elements. The elements are of the form:

```
$`/home/ricardo/MultiClass/data//Execucao_PUBLICACAO_DECISAO_INTERLOCUTORIA_DETERMINACAO_DE_PAGAMENTO/1117.txt.V1 

[1] DATA DE DISPONIBILIZACAO DA PUBLICACAO PELA FONTE OFICIAL: 16/11/2016 Pag 4279 Decisao Processo N RTOrd-0122200-90.2006.5.15.0087  <truncated>`
```

I would like to transform this in a two columns `dataframe` where:

```
c1       
The contents between $ and [1]

c2    
rest of the text
```

How can I do this split? Important to note that the numberof strings between `$` and `[1]` can change, and the strings `$`, `[ e ]` can appear in the rest of the text.

Thanks in advance,
Ricardo.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at these tips on how to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as this post on [creating a great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Perhaps the following tips on [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be worth a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(stringr)

string <- '$/home/ricardo/MultiClass/data//Execucao_PUBLICACAO_DECISAO_INTERLOCUTORIA_DETERMINACAO_DE_PAGAMENTO/1117.txt.V1 [1] DATA DE DISPONIBILIZACAO DA PUBLICACAO PELA FONTE OFICIAL: 16/11/2016 Pag 4279 Decisao Processo N RTOrd-0122200-90.2006.5.15.0087'

c1 <- str_match(string = string, pattern = "^\\$(.*) \\[1\\] (.*)")[,2]
c2 <- str_match(string = string, pattern = "^\\$(.*) \\[1\\] (.*)")[,3]
```

Comment: I suspect this isn't text input, but `list` output.

Comment: Yes. is a list.

Answer (score 1):

The `$ ...` text is the name of the list element, and the `[1] ...` is the value of that element. You can extract these (or better yet, assign them correctly when reading in your data).

```r
a <- list(`this is the name` = "data stored in that variable")

a
#> $`this is the name`
#> [1] "data stored in that variable"

names(a)
#> [1] "this is the name"

as.character(a)
#> [1] "data stored in that variable"
```